# Generate Full Random Number with Percentage Android

Tags: android, random, integer

I am trying to generate random number with percentage, something like this:

60% chance to generate number from 70 up to 100,

20% chance to generate number from 50 to 70

and so on
and then put it in TextView. But for some reason, I am getting some weird long decimal numbers like 0.44859123121 etc etc, how can I generate full numbers? like 99,80,70 etc etc.
This is my code:

```
Random rng = new Random();

    double doubl = Math.random();
            if (doubl < 0.6) {
                int r1 = rng.nextInt(100 - 70) + 70;
                // 60% chance 
            } else if (doubl < 0.65) {
                int r1 = rng.nextInt(0 - 30) + 0;
                // 5%
            } else if (doubl < 0.80) {
                // 15% chance 
                int r1 = rng.nextInt(30 - 50) + 30;
            } else {
                // 20% chance
                int r1 = rng.nextInt(50 - 70) + 50;
            }

            result.setText(doubl+"%");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the generated random integer `r1` in the result, not the `doubl` that is a random number between 0 and 1.

Also fix the calls to `nextInt()` so that you're not calling it with a negative value. For example `70 - 50` instead of `50 - 70`.